# SharePoint Code Access Security-requirements to call Page.TemplateControl.ParseControl

Tags: development, code-access-security

What are the CAS policy requirements to call the method [Page.TemplateControl.ParseControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz3ffe28%28loband%29.aspx)?

Specifically, in SharePoint I've tried to call the method in a Minimum-trust environment, but get this error on the page:

> Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

However, in a medium-trust environment, no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both TemplateControl and TemplateParser requires minimal AspNetHostingPermission's so that shouldn't be a problem.

Try using PermCalc.exe (part of .NET 2.0 framework) to identify permissions needed for your assembly. It will output a permissionset where you can check the Demand elements for required permissions.

Comment: Nothing personal - but could you please refrain from including "Hello", "HTH" and repeating your name? The reason is to increase the signal-to-noise ratio so that answers are as useful as possible in as little text as possible. More reasons why here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts ... Thanks :-)

Comment: gee i feel all fluffy now. Wasnt ment as self promtion tho, just common curtesy :-)

Comment: @Anders: Yes I know! To add to my first comment, up-votes are the best way of sharing the love on the site.